# mongoose findOne query with multiple conditions and "$gt" not returning proper results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am stumped by mongoose. I am trying to find a record that matches on both instanceId and currentQuantity. I can see the records in the database, and I know that currentQuantity is numeric not character. But these records are not being found by my query.
I have tried this:

```
titleRecords.findOne({"titleByDate.instanceId": 100156
         })
```

Result: returns the queries, but doesn't include the second condition which I need. So I tried this:

```
titleRecords.findOne({"titleByDate.instanceId": 100156
                                 , "titleByDate.currentQuantity": {"$gt": 0}
      })
```

Result: doesn't return the records I'm looking for (returns no records at all)

And I have tried this with extra brackets:

```
titleRecords.findOne({{"titleByDate.instanceId": 100156
                                 , "titleByDate.currentQuantity": {"$gt": 0}
      }})
```

Result: I get an error that the first { is unexpected

And I have tried this:

```
titleRecords.findOne({"titleByDate.instanceId": 100156
                                 , "titleByDate.currentQuantity": {$gt: 0}
      })
```

Result: doesn't return any records. I think quotes are required around "$gt" but honestly I'm so confused by mongoose syntax and can't for the life of me find any documentation of how to do this on mongoosejs.com

Per request, here are three sample records. The first query above returns the middle record - none of the others return anything. I apologize if this is not the right format to share the data in - please let me know if there is a better way

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "59936"
    },
    "titleByDate": {
        "currentQuantity": 4,
        "title": "ABC",
        "instanceId": 150351
    },
    "__v": 0
},

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "54936"
    },
    "titleByDate": {
        "currentQuantity": 2,
        "title": "QPR",
        "instanceId": 100156
    },
    "__v": 0
},


{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "51936"
    },
    "titleByDate": {
        "currentQuantity": 0,
        "title": "QQQ",
        "instanceId": 143159
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

And my model statement:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// define the schema for a play
var titleListingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title         : {
        titleId      : Number,
        title        : String,
     },
    titleByDate :{
        instanceId      : Number,
        title        :String,
        currentQuantity: Number
    }
 });
module.exports = mongoose.model('titleListing', titleListingSchema);
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data as well?

Comment: I have added three sample records with information about how they respond to the provided queries. Thank you for your help - I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Normal query to mongo console works fine. Can you share your model as well?

Comment: I added the model. I would like to do this using mongoose if possible as the rest of my code is in mongoose. And if this is a bug in mongoose then I feel I should report it to them somehow.

Comment: You need not export the mongoose model. Just get it by 
    `mymodel = mongoose.model('TheModel')`

Comment: Plus try running it with mongoose debug mode. It certainly worked for me. I am not sure why it's not working for you.

`mongoose.set('debug', true);`

did you insert data in DB manually???

Mongoose model name is case insensitive when it creates the collection in DB.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, I JUST figured out the problem. It was elsewhere in my program and resulted in the $gt:0 condition not being true. Sorry for not figuring it out sooner. SHould I delete this?